# <u> and pre-wrap: underlined spaces are collapsed between tag and text - Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a project where I need to preserve and display all underlined spaces in a sentence. I still need to collapse all other spaces.

I have `u {white-space:pre-wrap}` in my css but Chrome and Safari are collapsing all white space between the tag and the text. They do preserve all the other underlined spaces.

```
<u>     this     is     my     text     </u>
```

should be:

```
_____this____is_____my_____text_____
```

but Chrome displays it as:

```
this____is_____my_____text_____
```

http://codepen.io/ejg/pen/PPBBvG

`u {white-space:pre}` does work correctly but then I lose line-wrapping for the underlined part.

Is there any other way to preserve white space in `<u></u>`? Or some way to get Chrome/Safari to behave properly?

Comment: If you see this table https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values you'll see that pre-wrap wraps the spaces. It's a bug of chrome? Maybe. But it's better if you use `pre` instead of `pre-wrap` because you are not facing issues in this mode. Chrome sucks :)

Comment: The issues with this property are that the discussions may result in changes with future drafts, the name of the property may also change, and several values do not work at this time. Several of the proposed values which do not work include trim-inner, consume-before, and consume-after because the property is inherited, meaning that a <span> or <div> could cause more white space to be removed otherwise. See more: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/css3-new-ways-to-process-white-space/

Comment: If you want a workaround... In Chrome at least, using `span` with `text-decoration` seems to work correctly. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYxNed (Can't test Safari here, not the latest version that is)

Answer (score 0):

`pre-wrap` should work, maybe you are using an older version of chrime or safari? Both browsers use webkit, so maybe webkit is the problem, because all browsers render differently.